# how do I recursivley grep (or otherwise search for) hex strings

Tags: bash, grep, ksh

Long and short I'm trying to track down some files left by evil scum on a server.

> fgrep -r "STRING"  /path/here

has been working well for finding general stuff.

However, how do I search for hex patterns (you know... \xNN type strings).

Probably an easy question to answer but I've been spending too long starting at a bash screen !

Comment: My answer that suggests the use of the `[:xdigit:]` class (since deleted) searches for lines that have ASCII characters representing hex digits _not_ hex digits in the binary contents of the file. For the latter case, stick to Gnouc's answer.

Comment: @JosephR. I don't think there is anything wrong with `[[:xdigit:]]` - you just need to make it a sufficiently long sequence of them e.g. `[[:xdigit:]]{20}` such that the probability of a matching dictionary word becomes vanishingly small.

Comment: @steeldriver See Stephane's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean. Possibly with GNU `grep`:

```
grep -Ero '(\\x[[:xdigit:]]{2})+' .
```

To match strings of the format `\xNN` (the 4 characters backslash, `x` and two hexadecimal digits)